# Bootstrap - Add buttons to navbar on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to keep some menu items visible in the navbar, even in mobile view. So, it should not be included in the navbar toggle dropdown menu, but kept visible like on desktop view, next to the navbar toggle. I would need behavior similar to the `navbar-brand`, which stays visible even on mobile. Here is my current code, but I have no idea how to accomplish this:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand">Brand </a>

        </div>

        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp   ---->Here You Can See As Per Your Requirement !!  Inside " Responsive Utilities "  For You Just Use class="visible-lg"  Its Work Fine !! Thank U :)

Answer (score 1):

I've made this as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqv0bavc/

Basically, there's no reason you can't add another div in the header, float left or right, and then apply some basic styling:

```
.secondary-btns {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand">Brand </a>
  <div class="secondary-btns">
    <a href="#">btn</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any chance to use the same styling for that button as the menu items which get collapsed? (Without copying the CSS attributes)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the buttons receive styling from the navbar/nav classes, so some custom CSS is required.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand">Brand </a>

        </div>

        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Messages</a></li>
                <li class="visible-lg" ><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="visible-lg" ><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Contact Us</a></li>
                
                
                
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp   -- Can Use From Here as Per Your Requirement !!

Comment: class="visible-lg"   use this ....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is something magical to be done. I just tested

<a class="navbar-brand">Brand </a>
<a class="navbar-brand">Brand </a>

Instead of just

<a class="navbar-brand">Brand </a>

And it displayed well on mobile. You can give a font-size of say 110% to the second a-tag if you want it to be of a reduced size.

Just also tested the pull class as suggested above by Kümar. class="pull-left" maintains the first a-tag to the left and class="pull-right" to the second pushes it to the right.